# Planar cover of a rigid and non-planar graph

Tags: graphs, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a graph which is rigid and non-planar (e.g. $K_{3,3}$). Is it possible that $G$ has a planar cover?

Are there any studies on this topic?

Comment: The question has little do with computer science, and should thus be asked on Mathematics.

Comment: @Juho I thought we had consensus that [tag:graph-theory] was ontopic?

Comment: That said, the question is quite thin. What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Which research did you do?

Comment: @Raphael There seems to be a lot of cross-over between graph theory and CS but this question doesn't have any computational content, so it seems hard to justify it being on-topic here.